# Many errors when migrating from Poky Thud to Dunfell

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I upgraded my Yocto environment (Ubuntu 20.04) from version Thud to Dunfell. Suddenly I get lots of similar errors with many packages.
Below an example for "bitbake netcat" (from meta-openembedded layer, Dunfell branch) as well as for Busybox.

In the past I have upgraded Yocto several times, but never experienced this error. Anyone has an idea where this comes from ? Is there maybe an option in local.conf, which I am missing ?

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
ERROR: netcat-0.7.1-r3 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/netcat contained in package netcat requires ld-linux-armhf.so.3(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_netcat? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: netcat-0.7.1-r3 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/netcat contained in package netcat requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_netcat? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: netcat-0.7.1-r3 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/netcat contained in package netcat requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_netcat? [file-rdeps]

ERROR: busybox-1.31.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /bin/busybox.nosuid contained in package busybox requires libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_busybox? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: busybox-1.31.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /bin/busybox.nosuid contained in package busybox requires libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_busybox? [file-rdeps]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can skip the QA issue and move ahead by

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "file-rdeps"
```

or just give a try to upgrade the glibc package version as per dunfell release notes.